# Como substituir uma letra por um número em uma string em javascript?

Tags: javascript

Preciso nverter a string de uma mensagem recebida, e substituir as vogais utilizando a seguinte equivalência:

```
a = 4, e = 3, i = 2, o = 1, u = 0
```

E por fim, adicionar o sufixo 'ece'. Depois de tudo, retornar a mensagem encriptada. Por exemplo, `encrypt('banana')` retorna `'4n4n4bece'`.

Então implementei o seguinte código, mas não funciona. A parte que substitui as letras pelos números equivalentes não funciona.

```
function encrypt(mensagem){
    
    let msgArr = mensagem.split(' ');
    let msgArrReverse = msgArr.reverse();
      
    
    msgArrReverse.map((letra) => {
      letra = letra.replace('aeiou','43210');
    
    })
      
    let msgReverse = msgArrReverse.join('');
    const msgmEce = msgReverse.concat('ece')
    
    return msgmEce                               
}
```

Comment: A pergunta indicada no box azul acima tem várias respostas com soluções variadas, mas basicamente basta adaptá-las para o seu caso, trocando os símbolos pelas letras que você quer substituir.

Comment: Inclusive, as soluções do outro link são até melhores, principalmente os indicados [nesta resposta](/a/507313/112052), que dá pra adaptar facilmente pro seu caso: https://ideone.com/lC3XUo - assim não precisa ficar usando `split`, `reverse` e muito menos `map`, que é um exagero pra uma coisa tão simples :-)

Comment: Muito obrigada hkotsubo

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução que pode ajudar é essa aqui, comentei pra ficar um pouco mais didático.

```
function encrypt(texto) {
    //inverte a string
    texto.split();
    //troca os carateres
    texto.replace('a', 4).replace('e', 3).replace('i', 2)o.replace('o', 1).replace('u', 0)
    //adiciona o sufixo ece
    sufix = 'ece'
    textoEncryptado = texto + ' ' + 'ece'.
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigada Pedro